# Zepto animate callback not animating

Tags: javascript, css, animation, zepto

I'm attempting to make something similar to github's project viewer where after clicking a link the box moves to the left out of scene and then another box moves in from the right.

The way I attempted to do this is to have just a single div that's animated, and when you click the link the div moves to the left off the screen. Then in the callback of the first animate(), I call .css to move it to the right side of the page (without animating, so it just jumps there) then animate it again to move it back into view from the right.

Here's the JS

```
$('.mLink').on('click', function(e) {
    var 
            marginR = $('#mover').css('margin-right'),
            marginL = $('#mover').css('margin-left');

    $('#mover').animate({
            'margin-left': '-1500px',
            'margin-right': '1500px'
    }, 500, 'ease-out', function() {

            $('#mover').css({
                    'margin-left': '1500px',
                    'margin-right': '-1500px'
            });

            $('#mover').animate({
                    'margin-left': marginL,
                    'margin-right': marginR
            }, 500, 'ease-in');
    });
});
```

So what happens is that it animates to the left of the screen then jumps to the right side correctly but then appears in the proper location without actually doing the animation. I'm curious why this is occurring because it means animate() is executing just not showing the animation?

EDIT: for clarification

Comment: example at www.petejodo.com/newindex.html

Comment: I see that you have made it ease-in and ease-out. that is working fine in your link, what do you expect from this code. pls. define with more words, and CLARITY thank you.

Comment: i expect it to slide in from the right the same way it slid out to the left. is that what is occurring for you? if so what browser are you viewing it in? EDIT For me (chrome and firefox) the sliding to the left works just fine but then it just pops into place without animating (the 2nd animation)

Comment: I usually find that this happens when the range you want to move is exactly the size of the pane you are moving. so it doesn't "animate" but jumps. As a test, dbl the size of the range you want to move.

Comment: changing the range didnt help but i got it working with MarmiK's answer but have no idea why that works? really weird

Comment: Zepto uses CSS animation and after finish animation it resets the css animation time to zero second. with the call back animation it resets the css animation time back to provided value. this switching causes flickering and not smooth. You better use setTimeout for the second animation to kick start. Zepto's animation callback is not good for animation chaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, as I am not able to see all dependencies, and thus not able to create  fiddle for the same,

```
 $('.mLink').on('click', function(e) {
    var 
            marginR = $('#mover').css('margin-right'),
            marginL = $('#mover').css('margin-left');

    $('#mover').animate({
            'margin-left': '-1500px',
            'margin-right': '1500px'
    }, 500, 'ease-out', function() {

           $('#mover').animate({
               'margin-left': ' 1500px',
               'margin-right': '-1500px'
           }, 500, 'ease-in', function() {

                  $('#mover').animate({
                          'margin-left': marginL,
                          'margin-right': marginR
                  }, 500, 'ease-in', function(){return false;});
           });
    });
});
```

I hope this will do, as you want two effects you can have two functions. :) or more if you want or all together in one function.

Comment: this works for some reason I dont know why, now i'm just messing around with it cause the animation coming in from the right is a little laggy/not smooth. thanks! I'm gonna upvote you're answer but not mark it correct for now for the sake of a better solution. i'll mark it right if i can get the animation smooth using what you answered with or if no one else answers

Comment: while in the end i didn't really like this effect after all and am changing it, it is the correct solution. no need for the final callback of return false though. thanks